# Null Pointer Exception in GLProfile with JOGL 2.0

Tags: java, opengl, nullpointerexception, awt, jogl

JOGL 2.0 added a GLProfile parameter to GLCapabilities. For whatever reason, with this simple code:

```
import javax.media.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import javax.media.opengl.GLProfile;
import javax.media.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.getDefault()));
    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getProfileMap(GLProfile.java:1561)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.get(GLProfile.java:589)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:421)
    at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.getDefault(GLProfile.java:429)
    at com.setcorp.mosey.Test.main(Test.java:7)
```

So I cannot even create a GLCanvas for use in my JOGL 2.0 application.

Substituting in:

```
GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2)));
```

or

```
GLCanvas canvas = new GLCanvas(new GLCapabilities(null));
```

for line 7 gives me the same error.

I have set the build path to include newt.all.jar, jogl.all.jar, nativewindow.all.jar, and gluegen-rt.jar. I unzipped the dlls from their native jars and set the native library locations respectively in eclipse. I am using the jogl-2.0-b409-20110717-windows-i586 build and running W7, Intel Core 2 Duo T8100 2.10GHz, 2GB RAM, and Nvidia Quadro NVS 140M.

Is there an earlier build that would work for me?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. Just try it with only these jars in your build path (see below). Avoid including other jars when you try it.

- jogl.all.jar
- jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar
- gluegen-rt.jar
- gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar